# Google spreadsheet googlefinance get specific attribute does not work

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

The googlefinance integration, documented [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en), in google spreadsheets does not seem to work for me:

Example:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",TODAY()-30,TODAY())
```

Google spreadsheets gives the cell a red corner and prints the following message:
   `Fel i formeltolkning`. which in english means something along the lines of `Error in formatting`.

The following does however work: `=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG")`.

Also I can open other spreadsheets from links where the exakt same syntax seem to work. What can cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change comma to a semicolon.

`GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG";"price";TODAY()-30;TODAY())`

Some regions (Norway!) use a comma for decimals. The other option is to change settings:

`File > Spreadsheet Settings > Locale...`

Comment: Thank you, this solved it for me as well (lives in Sweden)